# Drools: adding multiple groups in a rule

Tags: drools

I need to assign more than one group in the agenda-group to a rule to be able to reuse it. For example, I would like to do something like this:

```
rule "Row 1 PromotionGlobalTest"
    agenda-group "global", "group1" //I want to do something like this
    enabled true
    salience 0
    dialect "mvel"
    when
        c : Contract( serviceType not in ( 2, 3 ) )
    then
        c.createMessage( "2, 3" );
end
```

[The idea is that there will be groups that share rules and that if you want to execute the rules of "group1", those that are exclusive to this group and those that are shared with another group will be executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlY5n.png)

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: You can only have one agenda-group on a rule -- eg. `agenda-group "<name>"`. You might be able to do something tricky with putting the LHS into its own rule and extending it, but you'll have to duplicate the RHS for each agenda-group.

Comment: Alternatively you could have a special agenda group that only contains this rule. Then instead of activating "global" or "group1" you'd first activate this agenda group and only afterwards activate your other groups.